# Remove splice function in Angular Material Pagination

Tags: angular, angular-material2

There is a an angular material data table with pagination which is used to display the data, the data is in the form of an array, the issue is when the next handle page is clicked the index value again starts from 1, but i need the data to have to continue index value.

Below is the code:-

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  ViewChild
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  MatPaginator,
  MatTableDataSource
} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Table with pagination
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-pagination-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-pagination-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-pagination-example.html',
})
export class TablePaginationExample implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name'];
  public array: any;
  public pageSize = 5;
  public currentPage = 0;
  public totalSize = 0;
  dataSource = [{
      position: 1,
      name: 'Hydrogen'
    },
    {
      position: 2,
      name: 'Helium'
    },
    {
      position: 3,
      name: 'Lithium'
    },
    {
      position: 4,
      name: 'Beryllium'
    },
    {
      position: 5,
      name: 'Boron'
    },
    {
      position: 6,
      name: 'Carbon'
    },
    {
      position: 7,
      name: 'Nitrogen'
    },
    {
      position: 8,
      name: 'Oxygen'
    },
    {
      position: 9,
      name: 'Fluorine'
    },
    {
      position: 10,
      name: 'Neon'
    },
    {
      position: 11,
      name: 'Sodium'
    },
    {`enter code here`
      position: 12,
      name: 'Magnesium'
    },
    {
      position: 13,
      name: 'Aluminum',
    },
    {
      position: 14,
      name: 'Silicon'
    },
    {
      position: 15,
      name: 'Phosphorus'
    },
  ]

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.array = this.dataSource;
    this.totalSize = this.dataSource.length;
    this.iterator();
    console.log(this.totalSize, "total size")
  }
  // function for pagination
  private iterator() {
    const end = (this.currentPage + 1) * this.pageSize;
    const start = this.currentPage * this.pageSize;
    const part = this.array.slice(start, end);
    this.dataSource = part;
  }
  public handlePage(e: any) {
    this.currentPage = e.pageIndex;
    this.pageSize = e.pageSize;
    this.iterator();
  }
export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}
```

```html
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element let i = index"> {{ i + 1 }} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
  <mat-paginator #paginator [pageSize]="pageSize" [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]" [showFirstLastButtons]="true" [length]="totalSize" [pageIndex]="currentPage" (page)="pageEvent = handlePage($event)">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

If an array has 10 values want to display 5 on the first page, so in the first-page index value will be from 1 to 5 and 
in Pagination the iterator() function is splicing the array value hence it's taking again from the index value 1 for the data 6 to 10th in next page.

Is there any way to avoid splicing in pagination.

Comment: why do you want to prevent it?

Comment: because I need to display data based on change function, and change function will apply only to first 5 data and next it be spliced and again change function has to to run to display next 5 data

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to prevent splicing? If the incorrect index value is showing on the next page is your problem then you can change your position column value as below to display the correct index on the next page:

```
 <!-- Position Column -->
<ng-container matColumnDef="position">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element let i = index"> {{ (pageSize*currentPage) + i + 1 }} </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I don't need splicing function because I have a change function, based on change  function i need to display the data, if i select 5 data to be displayed then  change function will apply to onle those 5 data, if i click on next, then next data from 6 to 10th will be empty and again i have to choose the change function